# HTTPS / SSL Tunneling

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have a problem with a https tunneling on Android.

I am getting a raw data request, from a device, and I have to send the data to a server, and get the response and forward it. 
The problem is that on Android, there seems to be issues with the connection to a secure server. Android asks me to create hostname verifiers, and there are issues like 501 HTTP Error code that I'm receiving

Does somebody know a way to forward some raw bytes to a server, get the response and don't handle anything? Some tunneling example or something?

Can somebody point me to some 3rd party library that handle this kind of situation?

Thanks,
Ark

Comment: i don't understand where the tunnel is ?

Comment: Tunneling between android device and a web server. To send data without knowing how the data it's encrypted or even knowing certificates, content, etc.

Comment: 'There seem to be issues', 'lots of issues' etc. are not adequate problem descriptions. I can't speak for Android but everything you need is built into Java proper, no third party libraries required.